# How to update this in real time rather than reloading browser again and again?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Am learning xhr, how to keep price loading in real time on browser? When we send GET request to the api, we receive a json response which has the price, I don't want to reload browser tab again and again to check price, I want it to update in real time, how to do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload  = function(){
    document.write(this.responseText)
};
xhr.open("GET","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json",true);
xhr.send();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is basically how to schedule your code to run in the future.  The built-in mechanisms for that are `setTimeout()`, which runs things once, and `setInterval()`, which runs them multiple times.  For example, you could:

```
setInterval(function () {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload  = function(){
    document.write(this.responseText)
  };
  xhr.open("GET","https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json",true);
  xhr.send();
}, 10 * 1000);
```

This runs your code every 10 seconds.  (`10` multiplied by `1000` milliseconds.)  There's a problem though, in that your GET request may take longer than 10 seconds to finish.  This is particularly true on bad mobile connections and high latency links, such as those of satellite users.  To solve that problem, you need to use `setTimeout()` instead, and trigger your code to run once the first request is finished.  You should be sure to also include the error case, as you don't want your loop to stop if there's just one error.  To make all this simpler, I'll switch to using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).  (Fetch is what you should be using these days.  It's more robust than XHR, and is well-supported by browsers.)

```
function updatePrices() {
  return fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/USD.json').then({
    if (res.ok) {
      throw new Error('Request failed');
    }
    return res.json()
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    setTimeout(updatePrices, 10 * 1000);
  }).catch((e) => {
    setTimeout(updatePrices, 5 * 1000); // If fail, try again sooner
  });
}
updatePrices();
```

Now, you have updates every 10 seconds.  But, you asked for *realtime*.  For that, you need a different tool.. [server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events).

If you are in control of the server, you can choose to support this simple text-based protocol.  This allows the server to push data to you immediately when its updated.  Setting up the event source on the client is very simple:

```
const eventSource = new EventSource('https://example.com/bitcoin-prices');
eventSource.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  console.log(e.data);
});
```

The EventSource will even reconnect if a connection is lost.

I hope this helps you get started!